# sqlite3 generate running total with repeated field value

Tags: sqlite

This has been driving me nuts because I feel like it should be possible.  But I'm admittedly not a huge SQL whiz.

I have an sqlite3 table that looks essentially like this:

```
id    date        amount
--    ----        ------
51    2018.10.01    10.0
52    2018.11.15   100.0
53    2018.11.15    20.0
54    2018.09.10   -30.0
```

(At least, these are the pertinent fields; the others have been left out).

What I want to do is generate a running total of the `amount` column, but with the data sorted by `date`.

I'm aware of the 'join the table with itself' trick for calculating a running total.  So if I wanted a new running total value for each `id` (which is a unique field), I can do this:

```
select T2.id, T2.date, T2.amount, sum(T2.amount)
from Transactions T1
inner join Transactions T2
on T1.id >= T2.id
group by T1.id
```

And I get this:

```
"51"    "2018.10.01"    "10.0"  "10.0"
"52"    "2018.11.15"    "100.0" "110.0"
"53"    "2018.11.15"    "20.0"  "130.0"
"54"    "2018.09.10"    "-30.0" "100.0"
```

Running total correct.

But if I want a running total on this data in `date` order, it breaks down.  This is close:

```
select T1.id, T2.date, T2.amount, sum(T2.amount)
from Transactions T1
inner join Transactions T2
on T1.date >= T2.date
group by T1.date
```

Except that it over-counts (and combines) the `amount` values in the two rows where `date` is `2018.11.15`.  Presumably because the `on T1.date >= T2.date` clause applies to both rows twice each.

```
"54"    "2018.09.10"    "-30.0" "-30.0"
"51"    "2018.09.10"    "-30.0" "-20.0"
"53"    "2018.09.10"    "-30.0" "200.0"
```

As I see it, this technique will only work if the `join` is performed on a field whose values are both unique and sorted.  Once I sort the table by `date`, the unique `id` values are out of order and no longer usable.

So then I thought -- maybe sort the table by `date` first, then add a temporary column of unique sorted numbers.  Simply the row number would do.

Unfortunately, this appears to be a version of sqlite that does not support any of `row_number()`, `rownum` or the `over` clause.

I'm aware of this technique for generating row numbers:

```
select id, date,
(select count(*) from Transactions T1 where T1.id <= T2.id)
from Transactions T2

"51"    "2018.10.01"    "1"
"52"    "2018.11.15"    "2"
"53"    "2018.11.15"    "3"
"54"    "2018.09.10"    "4"
```

But in no amount of fiddling around have I been able to figure out a way to:

- First sort the table by `date`
- Then use the `count(*)` technique to generate the unique row numbers
- Then `join` the table with itself to create the running total

in a single SQL statement.

Hope this makes sense.  Thanks for any thoughts anyone might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Sqlite 3.25 or better, window functions make this easy. Example:

First, populate a table with your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE example(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, amount REAL);
INSERT INTO example VALUES(51,'2018-10-01',10.0);
INSERT INTO example VALUES(52,'2018-11-15',100.0);
INSERT INTO example VALUES(53,'2018-11-15',20.0);
INSERT INTO example VALUES(54,'2018-09-10',-30.0);
```

(Note that I changed the date format to one that the sqlite date and time functions understand, as that makes life easier as soon as you want to do something more complicated than sorting them).

The query

```
SELECT *, sum(amount) OVER (ORDER BY date, id) AS running_total
FROM example
ORDER BY date, id;
```

produces:

```
id          date        amount      running_total
----------  ----------  ----------  -------------
54          2018-09-10  -30.0       -30.0        
51          2018-10-01  10.0        -20.0        
52          2018-11-15  100.0       80.0         
53          2018-11-15  20.0        100.0
```

If you're using an older version, you really should consider upgrading for more reasons than just having window functions.

Comment: Well, it's complicated.  My real use of sqlite3 is via a Python module.  I'm not even sure what version, but any functionality it's lacking I can probably make up for with Python code.  But I'm also using a sqlite3 browser (DB Browser for SQLite -- https://sqlitebrowser.org), in which I'm trying to define a suitable view on the table in question.  That is what doesn't seem to support window functions.  Or at least I can't find any evidence that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Shawn -- you put me on the track to an answer.

It looks like the most recent beta version of DB Browser for SQLite *does* support window functions (I presume because the latest version of SQLite itself does).

Problem solved!